# Dijkstra's algorithm for matrices

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I've been trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm in C++11 to work on matrices of arbitrary size. Specifically, I am interested in solving question 83 on Project Euler.

I appear to always run in to a situation where every node neighboring the current node has already been visited, which, if I understand the algorithm correctly, should never happen.

I've tried poking around in a debugger, and I've re-read the code several times, but I have no idea where I am going wrong.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <tuple>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cinttypes>

typedef std::tuple<size_t, size_t> Index;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Index i)
{
    os << "(" << std::get<0>(i) << ", " << std::get<1>(i) << ")";
    return os;
}

template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(size_t i, size_t j):
        n(i),
        m(j),
        xs(i * j)
    {}

    Matrix(size_t n, size_t m, const std::string& path):
        n(n),
        m(m),
        xs(n * m)
    {
        std::ifstream mat_in {path};
        char c;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < m - 1; ++j) {
                mat_in >> (*this)(i,j);
                mat_in >> c;
            }
            mat_in >> (*this)(i,m - 1);
        }
    }

    T& operator()(size_t i, size_t j)
    {
        return xs[n * i + j];
    }

    T& operator()(Index i)
    {
        return xs[n * std::get<0>(i) + std::get<1>(i)];
    }

    T operator()(Index i) const
    {
        return xs[n * std::get<0>(i) + std::get<1>(i)];
    }

    std::vector<Index> surrounding(Index ind) const
    {
        size_t i = std::get<0>(ind);
        size_t j = std::get<1>(ind);
        std::vector<Index> is;
        if (i > 0)
            is.push_back(Index(i - 1, j));
        if (i < n - 1)
            is.push_back(Index(i + 1, j));
        if (j > 0)
            is.push_back(Index(i, j - 1));
        if (j < m - 1)
            is.push_back(Index(i, j + 1));
        return is;
    }

    size_t rows() const { return n; }
    size_t cols() const { return m; }

private:
    size_t n;
    size_t m;
    std::vector<T> xs;
};

/* Finds the minimum sum of the weights of the nodes along a path from 1,1 to n,m using Dijkstra's algorithm modified for matrices */
int64_t shortest_path(const Matrix<int>& m)
{
    Index origin(0,0);
    Index current { m.rows() - 1, m.cols() - 1 };
    Matrix<int64_t> nodes(m.rows(), m.cols());
    std::set<Index> in_path;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m.rows(); ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < m.cols(); ++j)
            nodes(i,j) = INTMAX_MAX;
    nodes(current) = m(current);
    while (1) {
        auto is = m.surrounding(current);
        Index next = origin;
        for (auto i : is) {
            if (in_path.find(i) == in_path.end()) {
                nodes(i) = std::min(nodes(i), nodes(current) + m(i));
                if (nodes(i) < nodes(next))
                    next = i;
            }
        }
        in_path.insert(current);
        current = next;
        if (current == origin)
            return nodes(current);
    }
}

int64_t at(const Matrix<int64_t>& m, const Index& i) { return m(i); }
int at(const Matrix<int>& m, const Index& i) { return m(i); }

int main()
{
    Matrix<int> m(80,80,"mat.txt");
    printf("%" PRIi64 "\n", shortest_path(m));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Clearly, all neighbors of the current node can have been visited! Just think of a graph with two nodes: when the non-start node is visited clearly all neighbor nodes, i.e., the start node, have been visited. Looking at your implementation you don't seem to implement [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm): there is no priority queue anywhere to be seen.

Comment: Yes, but in that case, you are at the destination node, and so you are done. Can the situation still arise even if you are not on the destination node? If so, where should you go next?

Comment: Sure it can arise. Just take a graph consisting of one center node and multiple nodes each only connected to the center node. If the destination node doesn't have the shortest distance from the start you'll immediately end up at a node with all neighbors visited. If you insist on a grid, you'll need to be a bit more careful with the construction but it is easy for a corner to be visited after its adjacent nodes. Either way, [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) doesn't care at all about that situation.

Comment: @user3468950 if your intention is ONLY solving problem 83 of Project Euler, your code seems a bit over-complicated. You can implement a simpler Dijkstra without using the priority queue (which I don't see in your code), but just iterating and finding the minimum, more tailored to the situation.

Comment: The 'graph' construction from the given matrix is not so obvious to me. This is because the costs are associated with the vertices and not the edges. You may need to follow the advice outlined in the answer to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592420/finding-a-shortest-path-in-a-graph-with-node-and-edge-weights

Answer (score 1):

You do not understand the algorithm correctly.  There is nothing stopping you from running into dead ends.  As long as there are other options you have not yet explored, just mark it as a dead end and move on.

BTW I agree with commentators who say that you are overcomplicating the solution.  It suffices to create a matrix of "cost to get to here" and have a queue of points to explore paths from.  Initialize the total cost matrix to a value for NOT_VISITED, -1 would work.  For each point, you look at the neighbors.  If the neighbor either has not been visited, or you just found a cheaper path to it, then adjust the cost matrix and add the point to the queue.

Keep going until the queue is empty.  And then you have guaranteed lowest costs everywhere.

A* is a lot more efficient than this naive approach, but what I just described is more than efficient enough to solve the problem.